# How to use VContainer to instantiate a prefab and register attached monobehaviours

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I've been working on introducing IoC containers into my project early on and am currently trying to use VContainer (https://vcontainer.hadashikick.jp/). I'm having trouble understanding the documentation for it though, and I can't figure out how exactly to instantiate a gameobject prefab and then register the components on it. VContainer has a function in its builder called `RegisterComponentInNewPrefab` but this doesn't seem to be used for this purpose.

The below code snippet lives on an empty gameobject in the scene, and runs on boot. I am trying to instantiate the player gameobject from a prefab, and then register the monobehaviours attached to it so they can be injected into other scripts when needed.

```cs
public class SimulationLifetimeScope : LifetimeScope
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject prefab;

    protected override void Configure(IContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        InstallGameObject(builder);
        InstallPlayerControllers(builder)
    }

    private void InstallGameObject(IContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var playerObject = Object.Instantiate(prefab);
        Container.InjectGameObject(playerObject);       
    }

    private void InstallPlayerControllers(IContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register<PlayerController>(Lifetime.Singleton);
        builder.Register<PlayerFacade>(Lifetime.Singleton);
        builder.Register<Collectable>(Lifetime.Singleton);
    }
}
```

`Container` is an `IObjectResolver` type, and should be set up in the base class `LifetimeScope`, but when called here in code it's null and so unity errors out at that stage. How would I do this correctly?

**Edit:**
Here's the `PlayerController` script, as well as the current `PlayerFacade` script that's currently just used to test if the player controller is injected correctly (both sit on the same game object prefab, which is instantiated on game start by VContainer).

```cs
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private PlayerData playerData;
    [SerializeField] private Transform collectableParent;

    private Transform cameraTransform;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private InputControl playerInputActions;
    private Vector2 leftInputVector= Vector2.zero;
    private float size;

    private void Start()
    {        
        cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;        

        //Input
        playerInputActions = new InputControl();
        playerInputActions.PlayerBallMovement.Enable();
        size = playerData.StartingSize;
    } 

    void Update()
    {
        leftInputVector = playerInputActions.PlayerBallMovement.LeftStickDirection.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Move();
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        var dragForce = -rb.velocity * playerData.PlayerDrag;
        dragForce.y = 0f;
        var force = new Vector3(leftInputVector.x, 0, leftInputVector.y);
        
        //camera stuff
        //todo move this elsewhere and make nicer
        var cameraForward = cameraTransform.forward;
        var cameraRight = cameraTransform.right;
        cameraForward.y = 0f;
        cameraRight.y = 0f;
        cameraForward = cameraForward.normalized;
        cameraRight = cameraRight.normalized;
        
        var totalMovementVector = (force.z * cameraForward) + (force.x * cameraRight) + dragForce;

        rb.AddForce(totalMovementVector * playerData.PlayerSpeed, ForceMode.Acceleration);
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        collision.gameObject.TryGetComponent<Collectable>(out var collectable);
        var closestHitPoint = collision.collider.ClosestPointOnBounds(gameObject.transform.position);
        
        if (collectable == null || !collectable.TryPickedUp(this, closestHitPoint)) 
            return;

        size += collectable.Size;
    }
}
```

```cs
public class PlayerFacade : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Inject] private PlayerController PlayerController;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (PlayerController == null)
           Debug.Log("player controller inject is null on start");
        else
            Debug.Log("player controller inject is not null on start");
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (PlayerController == null)
            Debug.Log("player controller null in update loop");
        else
            Debug.Log("player controller not null in update loop");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass `Compornent` to `RegisterComponentInNewPrefab`. Since most objects are `GameObjects`, I think it is not possible to specify this to avoid confusion.

Below is the test code for the minimum configuration.
BTW: The parent class of `MonoBehaviour` is `Component`.

```
using VContainer;
using VContainer.Unity;
using UnityEngine;

// SimulationLifetimeScope.cs
public sealed class SimulationLifetimeScope : LifetimeScope
{
    [SerializeField] Player prefab;

    protected override void Configure(IContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterComponentInNewPrefab<Player>(prefab, Lifetime.Singleton);
        builder.RegisterEntryPoint<RequiresPlayerEntryPoint>();
    }
}

// Player.cs
public sealed class Player : MonoBehaviour {}

// RequiresPlayerEntryPoint.cs
public sealed class RequiresPlayerEntryPoint : IInitializable
{
    public RequiresPlayerEntryPoint(Player player)
         => Debug.Log(player); // Player(Clone) (Player)

    public void Initialize() {}
}
```

**Edit: If the scripts are attached to the same object**

It may be necessary to generate and register components on your own. The reason is that each API is only generated at registration.

[image]

```
using VContainer;
using VContainer.Unity;
using UnityEngine;

public sealed class SimulationLifetimeScope : LifetimeScope
{
    [SerializeField] Player prefab;

    protected override void Configure(IContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var obj = Instantiate<Player>(prefab);
        builder.RegisterComponent<Player>(obj);
        builder.RegisterComponent<PlayerController>(obj.GetComponent<PlayerController>());
        builder.RegisterComponent<PlayerFacade>(obj.GetComponent<PlayerFacade>());
        builder.RegisterEntryPoint<RequiresPlayerEntryPoint>();
    }
}

// RequiresPlayerEntryPoint.cs

public sealed class RequiresPlayerEntryPoint : IInitializable
{
    public RequiresPlayerEntryPoint(Player player, PlayerController controller, PlayerFacade facade)
    {
        Debug.Log(player);
        Debug.Log(controller); 
        Debug.Log(facade); 
    }

    public void Initialize() {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! When I go to inject the `PlayerController` after registering the component in this way though it's still null (I just currently have it injecting into the `PlayerFacade` and then print out if it's null or not on start and on update). Is there some other step I could have missed?

Comment: @Tycho9000 Can you please provide the PlayerController code? I am unable to determine this as my registration is normal.

Comment: Can do, I've edited the question to include the `PlayerController` script, as well as the `PlayerFacade` script as that's where I'm currently testing if the inject is working (in case the issue is actually in that script instead)

Comment: To resolve MonoBehaviour dependencies, you must use [Auto Inject Game Objects](https://vcontainer.hadashikick.jp/resolving/gameobject-injection) or [Register MonoBehaviour](https://vcontainer.hadashikick.jp/registering/register-monobehaviour). Have you solved this one?

Comment: The MonoBehaviours should get instantiated at runtime on the prefab, so I've changed the `Register` calls in the `InstallPlayerControllers` function to `RegisterComponent` ones. I still can't seem to then register/instantiate the prefab correctly though, it feels off to register the components individually and then need to specifically register a prefab one in order to get it to instantiate. I tried using `Container.Instantiate` instead, but since the container seems to not be created yet that errors out.

Comment: Are all scripts attached to the same object? If so, please take a look at the edited answer.

Comment: That's fixed it, thanks! Just need to get it working across assemblies now, but that's unrelated to this question so going to mark it answered, thanks so much!